# how could I load the Google map in terrain view in iphone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm new in iPhone. How could I load the Google map in terrain view. 
MKMapView provides only three options, MKMapTypeStandard, MKMapTypeSatellite, MKMapTypeHybrid.

But I want to show the terrain view, how could I do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the value of the `mapType` property on your `MKMapView` instance to 3 (instead of using one of the named constants):

```
yourMapView.mapType = 3;
```

Works for me when compiling against the 5.0 SDK. No idea if it'll get through the app store approval process...

Comment: I am surprised that there are very few question on stackOveflow regarding this terrain type. Thanks a lot for pointing out that.

Comment: I should point out that this will probably no longer work in the next major iOS release.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem.
You have to use the webview and html file which contains the javascript and Google maps API.
Just load the html file in webkit which loads the maps.google.com page and the Google maps API directly show  the terrain view without interacting with webview.