# MKMapView mapTypes

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Until recently I thought there are only three options that can be set to MKMapView mapType.

```
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
```

But as mentioned in this link [how could I load the Google map in terrain view in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041068/how-could-i-load-the-google-map-in-terrain-view-in-iphone), one can also get "Terrain type(not mentioned in docs)" by setting

```
[mapView setMapType:3];
```

Interesting thing is maximum zoom in allowed in Terrain mode is different from other `native` modes. Instead of 3 above I tried integers <3 but that does not work(MapView shows `Standard` type only).
Does anyone know if there are more options to set as type of `MKMapView`?

> Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also looking for that, I want 3D view, please let us know.

Answer (score 6):

I came across this problem too. I'd used `[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];` in my `init` method and the map type wouldn't change.

What fixed it was moving that line to my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
}
```